# Creating A Client Connect Log-How To Change Code For Last Connect

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266

This is the standard routine found all over the internet for
obtaining the IP/MAC address of an connected client. It works.
What I can't figure out is how to get only the last MAC to access to keep an access log.
I don't want a repeat of every connect, each time there's a new connect.
I can't find docs on STAILQ_NEXT, so I don't know what it is doing.
Help appreciated.

````
  unsigned char number_client;
  struct station_info *stat_info;
//  struct ip_addr *IPaddress;
  struct ip4_addr *IPaddress;
  IPAddress address;
  int i=1;
  number_client= wifi_softap_get_station_num();
  stat_info = wifi_softap_get_station_info();
  Serial.print(" Total Connected Clients are = ");
  Serial.println(number_client);
    while (stat_info != NULL) {
      IPaddress = &stat_info->ip;
      address = IPaddress->addr;
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[0],HEX);Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[1],HEX);Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[2],HEX);Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[3],HEX);Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[4],HEX);Serial.print(':');
      Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[5],HEX);Serial.print(' ');
      stat_info = STAILQ_NEXT(stat_info, next);
      i++;
      Serial.println();
    }
  delay(500);
}```



================================
Thanks Majenko. This gives me the MAC, but if I got the rest of the code correct, this is always giving me the last MAC to connect, rather than the last MAC to access the page. If there are 3 connected A, B, C and A refreshes, the log shows C. Not sure if the list if FIFO or LIFO or FILO or ??? or there's something else I am missing. Maybe I am looking at the wrong variable or ???

    ```void clientMAC(){
      struct station_info *scan = wifi_softap_get_station_info();
      byte MAClast[5];
      if (scan != NULL) { // Check there is at least one entry
        while (STAILQ_NEXT(scan, next) != NULL) {
            scan = STAILQ_NEXT(scan, next);
        }
        // scan now points to the last entry
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[0],HEX);Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[1],HEX);Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[2],HEX);Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[3],HEX);Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[4],HEX);Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(scan->bssid[5],HEX);Serial.print(' ');
      }else { // We have no entries
     }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`stat_info` is a simple *linked list* of type `struct station_info *`, with a predefined structure imposed by the SDK. Here's the full chain of implementation:

```cpp
struct station_info {
    STAILQ_ENTRY(station_info)    next;

    uint8 bssid[6];
    struct ipv4_addr ip;
};
```

The `STAILQ_ENTRY(station_info) next` macro expands to:

```cpp
    struct {                                
        struct station_info *stqe_next; /* next element */          
    } next;
```

So you have a linked list that is based around `stat_info->next.stqe_next`.

The macro `STAILQ_NEXT(stat_info, next)` just wraps that in a bit of abstraction to make iterating easier. It expands out to `((stat_info)->next.stqe_next`.

To get the last element of a linked list you need to iterate through the list until `->next.stqe_next` is null, at which point you know you are at the end of the list.  For example:

```cpp
struct station_info *scan = wifi_softap_get_station_info();
if (scan != NULL) { // Check there is at least one entry
    while (STAILQ_NEXT(scan, next) != NULL) {
        scan = STAILQ_NEXT(scan, next);
    }
    // scan now points to the last entry
} else {
    // We have no entries
}
```

Comment: Thanks Majenko. Please see my answer in the original post (I was not sure how to directly respond to your answer).

Comment: @tsb Accessing the page and connecting to the AP are two completely different things. To find who accessed the page last you need code at the page serving level, not at the AP connecting level.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a hint as to how that happens?